# How to install additional software on a Netkit virtual machine?

Tags: gcc, virtual-machine

I'm trying to **use [Netkit](http://wiki.netkit.org/index.php/Main_Page)** to test some of my C applications. In order to do so, I need to have `gcc` installed on my virtual machines. So I'm trying to install it following [the instructions in the wiki](http://wiki.netkit.org/index.php/FAQ#How_can_I_install.2Fupgrade_packages_or_other_additional_software_inside_Netkit.3F). The second thing to do would be this:

> Once vm has started, configure a name server inside its resolv.conf file

Here's what I find inside `/etc/resolv.conf` of the virtual machine:

```
#domain local.domain.nam
#nameserver w.x.y.z
#search suffix.for.unqualified.names
```

What should I write there? **How to configure a name server?** I tried to copy the `resolv.conf` of my host but it doesn't work.

If I try to run `apt-get update` here's the output I get:

[image: Error messages displayed in after apt-get update]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at `/etc/resolv.conf` on the host and add the `nameserver` lines found there to the guest file.  Or you can use third-party recursive name servers.  Here are some publicly accessible servers:

- [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)
- [Verisign](https://www.verisign.com/en_US/security-services/public-dns/index.xhtml)

Note that Debian's APT configuration apparently contains unstable/sid repositories (based on the `…/unstable/…` part in the URLs).  If the VM image was created a long time ago, this will make updates and installing additional software very difficult because the unstable/sid has evolved considerably since then, and upgrades for historic unstable to current versions does not always work.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for updating. In particular, as I used Google's one, I just had to write the following lines in `resolv.conf`.
`nameserver 8.8.8.8`
`nameserver 8.8.4.4`

Still I can't manage to install `gcc` (for *unmet dependecies*). But maybe that's a topic for another question?

Comment: I added a note about unstable. But yes, it's a topic for a different question.